# bochner-kodaira formula on kahler manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a compact Kahler manifold. Given a vector field $V = V^i \partial_{z_i} + V^{\overline{i}} \partial_{\overline{z_i}}$ on $M$, how do I show the Bochner-Kodaira formula:

$||\nabla V||^2 = ||\overline{\nabla} V||^2 + \int_M R_{\overline{j}i}V^i \overline{V^{\overline{j}}} \omega^n$

$\nabla V$ is $(1,0)$-form $TM^{\mathbb{C}}$-valued given in local coordinate by:

$\nabla V = (\partial_jV^i + V^a\Gamma^i_{ja}) dz_j \otimes \partial_{z_i} + \partial_{j}V^{\overline{i}} dz_j \otimes \partial_{\overline{z_i}}$

Similarly, $\overline{\nabla}$ is defined in local coordinate by:

$\overline{\nabla} V = (\partial_{\overline{j}}V^{\overline{i}} + V^{\overline{a}}\overline{\Gamma^i_{ja}}) d\overline{z_j} \otimes \partial_{\overline{z_i}} + \partial_{\overline{j}}V^{\overline{i}} d\overline{z_j} \otimes \partial_{z_i}$

Comment: Instead of proving directly the integral formula, you could try to compare $\nabla^*\nabla$ and $\bar{\nabla}^*\bar{\nabla}$ using a system of normal Kähler coordinates

Comment: I tried to write out both terms $||\nabla V||$ and $||\overline{\nabla}V||$ in normal coordinate, but it is not clear to me how to make the Ricci tensor terms appear.

Comment: I'm curious, what is your reference for this identity?

Comment: It is  equation (3.3)  in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412185.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that, in the paper you linked, the authors were using slightly different conventions: $V$ is a $(1,0)$-vector field on a Kähler manifold, so that $\nabla_aV^b=\partial_aV^b+\Gamma^b_{ac}V^c$ and $\nabla_{\bar{a}}V^b=\partial_{\bar{a}}V^b$, and $\nabla$ is the $(1,0)$-part of a connection while $\bar{\nabla}$ is the $(0,1)$-part. Now, the pairings can be rewritten as
$$\lVert \nabla V\rVert^2=\left\langle V,\nabla^*\nabla V\right\rangle_{L^2(g)}$$
$$\lVert \bar{\nabla}V\rVert^2=\lVert \bar{\partial}V\rVert^2=\left\langle V,\bar{\partial}^*\bar{\partial} V\right\rangle_{L^2(g)}$$
so the formula you seek follows from the usual Nakano-Bochner identity applied to the holomorphic vector bundle $T^{1,0}M$ with Hermitian metric $g$. You can find it, together with a proof, as Corollary $1.3$ in [Demailly's notes](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf).

Comment: You forgot squares on all norms

Comment: @Didier thanks, I fixed it now.